# Unable to process a JSON formated file with multiple records in Pentaho Data Integration

Tags: json, pentaho

I am having a problem getting the JSON INPUT step to process multiple JSON records within a single file. If there is only one line in the file:

```
{"unit_record":[{"TERM":"201220","INST_METHOD":"TR"}]}
```

Then it processes just fine. However as soon as there is more than one JSON record in the file, the JSON INPUT step says there are no rows:

```
{"unit_record":[{"TERM":"201220","INST_METHOD":"TR"}]}
{"unit_record":[{"TERM":"200910","INST_METHOD":"IN"}]}
```

Perhaps my REGEX is incorrect? Here is what I have in my JSON INPUT step for the path for each column:

```
$.unit_record[*.TERM]
$.unit_record[*.INSTRUCTIONAL_METHOD]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make as JSON array like this

[{"unit_record":[{"TERM":"201220","INST_METHOD":"TR"}]},
{"unit_record":[{"TERM":"200910","INST_METHOD":"IN"}]}]

Now if you try in JSON INPUT STEP it will work fine